# Fortran: Cray Pointers and Derived Data Types

Tags: pointers, fortran

I've got a derived data type in fortran wich looks like this:

```
TYPE mytype
        INTEGER a
        DOUBLE COMPLEX, dimension(:), allocatable :: elem
END TYPE mytype
```

Now I want to program a function which gets a DOUBLE COMPLEX array as an argument. This array should become the array "elem" of "mytype" without allocating memory and copying the data. I tried to use a cray pointer in the following way:

```
DOUBLE COMPLEX, INTENT(IN) :: eleminput(5) !input array which should become x%elem
TYPE(mytype) :: x
pointer(xpntr,x%elem)
xpntr = LOC(eleminput)
```

When I try to compile I get an error saying it is expacting ")" instead of "%" in the line "pointer(xpntr,x%elem)". So it seems cray pointers don't work with elements of a derived data type. Is there a possibility to get this working with or also without cray pointers? The derived data type can not be changed. I hope you unterstand my question and thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the eleminput argument have the value that you want x%elem to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move an allocation.  If the eleminput argument is allocatable:

```
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
type mytype
  integer :: a
  complex(kind=dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: elem
end type

...    

subroutine foo(eleminput)
  complex(kind=dp), intent(inout), allocatable :: eleminput(:)
  type(mytype) :: x
  call move_alloc(eleminput, x%elem)
  !...  work with x
end subroutine foo
```

An actual argument associated with an allocatable dummy argument must itself be allocatable - that is - the call to `foo` must look something like:

```
complex(kind=dp), allocatable :: fred(:)
fred = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
call foo(fred)
```

Because the allocation is moved out of the dummy argument `eleminput` inside the subroutine `foo`, the actual argument `fred` will be unallocated when that subroutine returns.

Answer (score 2):

Cray pointers don't work with with allocatables.  I would advise strongly against using Cray pointer in new code, because Cray pointers differ subtly in implementation detail, and normal Fortran pointers work here:

```
module bar
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)
  TYPE mytype
     INTEGER:: a
     complex(kind=dp), dimension(:), allocatable :: elem
  END TYPE mytype

contains

  subroutine foo(eleminput)
    complex(kind=dp), dimension(:), intent(out), pointer :: eleminput
    type(mytype), target, save : : x
    allocate (x%elem(.....))
    eleminput => x%elem
  end subroutine foo
end module bar
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there also a possibility without changing mytype%elem to a pointer?

Comment: I think the editet version should work.  `elem` is now allocatable, and it is also important to add the `save` to x or it will be deallocated after leaving foo (not a good idea if you still keep around a pointer to it).  Also guard the allocate statement so you don't allocate twice.